# Rake Task with Ubuntu's Systemd through Bundler, exit status 127

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, bundler, sidekiq, systemd

I am setting up my project on Ubuntu 18.04 server with ruby's rake tasks (no Rails) that are meant to be background jobs. I want to write a systemd script to start my rake task (which starts an instance of a sidekiq worker).

**/lib/systemd/system/sidekiq_scheduler.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq_scheduler
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/trawler
ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle exec rake workers:scheduler
User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002

Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service does not properly run after calling systemctl enable and start. The systemctl status output is shown below.

```
● sidekiq_scheduler.service - sidekiq_scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sidekiq_scheduler.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-08-02 08:09:24 UTC; 4min 26s ago
  Process: 27376 ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle exec rake workers:scheduler (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 27376 (code=exited, status=127)
Aug 02 08:09:22 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 02 08:09:22 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: Stopped sidekiq_scheduler.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: sidekiq_scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 08:09:24 solaris-hive systemd[1]: Failed to start sidekiq_scheduler.
```

When I manually cd into '/home/deploy/trawler' (the working directory in the service file) and run the Execstart command manually (/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle exec rake workers:scheduler) I have no issues.

I have looked into other solutions but to my knowledge they don't seem to apply. Bundle exec should be an executable and works on its own. I also read that the program could simply have finished and systemd exited. I don't see why that would happen though, as the sidekiq worker loaded directly works just fine and stays open operating jobs as it should.

EDIT

In order to clarify. My question is why does the systemd job have exit-code 127? I apologize if that terminology is not quite right, but I am expecting my Sidekiq job to run indefinitely, and it seemingly is not doing so. I have tried a few new things such as writing a script:

*/home/deploy/bin/scheduler.sh*

```
cd /home/deploy/trawler
rake workers:scheduler
```

And updating the following (the rest of the file is unchanged):

*/lib/systemd/system/sidekiq_scheduler.service (updated)*

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/deploy/bin/scheduler.sh
```

This is leading to the exact same issue. I can execute the script manually just I have in the ExecStart command, but it does not seem to work in the systemd service. Am I misunderstanding the exit-code: 'Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a'? Why does the rake task run indefinitely, but the systemd service quits almost immediately?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When you run it manually, you run it from the login shell, meaning you have the `PATH` updated with `/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin`. `systemctl` does not load any dotfiles by default. Try `ExecStart=PATH=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:$PATH bundle exec rake workers:scheduler`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mudosobwa, but that did not quite work. "Executable path is not absolute: PATH=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:$PATH bundle exec rake workers:scheduler"

Comment: You have to source rvm, for example: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh; /root/workspace/scripts/dns-updater.rb'`